Similarity between Field Extension Towers and Tensor Products
Let $F$ be a field.

Consider field extension $ F \subset L \subset K $. Let $ \alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_m $ be an $F$-basis of $ L $, $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$ an $L$-basis of $ K $. By  the theory of field extension, one knows that $ \{ \alpha_i \beta_j \}_{i,j} $ is an $F$-basis of $K$. In particular,
$$
\dim_F (K) = \dim_L (K) \dim_F (L).
$$

Let $V, W$ be $F$-vector space with basis $\{ x_i \}_{1 \le i \le m}$, $\{ y_j \}_{1 \le j \le n}$ respectively. By the theory of tensor product, one knows that $ \{ x_i \otimes y_j \}_{i,j} $ is an $F$-basis of $V \otimes_F W$. In particular,
$$
\dim_F (V \otimes_F W) = \dim_F (V) \dim_F (W).
$$


My question is that: There seems some similarity between them but I can't tell what it is.
I tried to make the first phenomenon a special case of tensor product but failed. Because $L/F$ is an $F$-vector space, and $K / L$ is an $L$-vector space, neither can I use $\otimes_F$ nor $\otimes_L$ to stick them together. I also tried to explain $L / F$ as an $(F,L)$-module, and $K/L$ an $(L, K)$-module, and use $\otimes_L$ to stick them together, but it seems quite "non-natural".
So, I wonder if there is indeed some relationship between (1) and (2), or it is possible to find a more general theory to explain the similarity between (1) and (2).
Thank you for taking time to read.

I found it is actually quite easy to explain. Let $A$ be an $F$-basis of $L$, and $B$ be an $L$-basis of $K$. Then:
$$
K 
= \bigoplus_{\beta \in B} L \beta
= \bigoplus_{\beta \in B} \left( \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} F \alpha \right) \beta
\simeq \bigoplus_{(\alpha, \beta) \in A \times B} F ( \alpha, \beta).
$$
That is to say, $K \simeq F^{\oplus (A \times B)}$.
Now let us consider the case of tensor product. Let $V = F^{\oplus A}$, $W = F^{\oplus B}$. Then
$$
V \otimes_F W
=
\left( \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} F \alpha \right) 
\otimes_F
\left( \bigoplus_{\beta \in B} F \beta \right)
\simeq
\bigoplus_{(\alpha, \beta) \in A \times B} F \alpha \otimes_F F\beta
\simeq
\bigoplus_{(\alpha, \beta) \in A \times B} F.
$$
i.e. $V \otimes_F W \simeq F^{\oplus (A \times B)}$.
So loosely speaking, (1) is a special case of
$$\tag{a}
\varinjlim_{i} \left( \varinjlim \alpha (i, \cdot ) \right)
\simeq 
\varinjlim \alpha.
$$
And (2) depends on the property of tensor product. I'm not sure whether (2) can be explained by (a), but this explain is enough for me now.
